# Adobe TLF and HTML

Tags: html, apache-flex, flash, adobe, tlf

What is the best way to convert a tlf markup to HTML? I want only standar HTML without the old font tag. I think I saw a utility created by someone for this, but I can remember where it is. any ideas?

Tks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3_Flex/WSc3ff6d0ea7785946579a18b01205e1c5646-7fef.html

```
var ptext:String = "Hello, World"; 
var flow:TextFlow = TextConverter.importToFlow(ptext, TextConverter.PLAIN_TEXT_FORMAT); 
var out:XML = TextConverter.export(flow, TextConverter.TEXT_LAYOUT_FORMAT, ConversionType.XML_TYPE );
```

but use `TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT` instead of `TextConverter.PLAIN_TEXT_FORMAT`

Comment: thanks for the response. The problem with this method is that it returns very very very old HTML, with the "font" tag. I want standard HTMl with paraghas and styles.

Comment: yeap, @vov11 it's bad but I think with core functions we will not get better export. You could write additional e4x parser to replace old font tags to CSS style as you want. let me know.